# Button link to different ID with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a single down arrow that jumps to the next ID on the page as you scroll down. I don't really know JavaScript so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible. I thought, as there are only a few sections, that I could just hide and display different divs with arrows that have different targets. I used two different codes to arrive at this, but doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 800) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("arrow");
        elem.setAttribute("style","display:none;");
    } else {
        elem.setAttribute("style","display:inline;");
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: There seems to be some errors in your js. You need to declare the elem variable outisde of the window.scroll. As you are using jQuery you can just do var elem = $("#arrow");

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to use code found in another example. Perhaps I misunderstood how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but your code can be simplified a bit by taking advantage of the shortcuts that jQuery provides.

```
//When the document is ready...
$(function(){
  //Select the arrow just once
  var arrow = $("#arrow");

  //Attach a scroll event to the window
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    //See what the scroll position is
    var scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;

    //When the document has scrolled to a certain point or more, hide the arrow.
    //Otherwise, show it.
    if(scrollPos >= 800){
       arrow.hide();
    } else {
       arrow.show();
    }

  });

});
```

---

Here's a brief demo of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Bt35Q/

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks for your help. I did also notice I had put the script in the header before the page called the jquery script, could this have been causing problems?

Comment: Yes, this script needs to occur AFTER the jQuery library has been loaded since this makes use of it.  Glad this worked for you!  Please mark my answer as accepted if it was the final solution if you don't mind :)